# How to extract the pixels of a shadow in an image in order to calculate the length?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm taking a picture every minute of a sundial. I want to create a python program which calculates the altitude of the sun based on the length of the shadows captured in the image. Below is such an image.
[image: Picture of the image to be processed.]

I tried to obtain the shadows by using multi-otsu thresholding on the V-channel of the image (I determined this channel contained the most information after plotting histograms of RGB and HSV channels). This results in the following division of the image for two classes:
[image: Thresholded image]

I'm not sure how to treat the picture further, or if I should've treated it differently to obtain the shadows. I also don't know how to extract the length of the shadows if this is the best extraction of the shadows. I've read about blobs but didn't have success applying them yet. Any pointers on how to proceed / or how to best extract the shadows are appreciated.

Here is some of the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu

def applyMultiOtsu(image, classes):
    # Setting the font size for all plots.
    matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 9

    # Applying multi-Otsu threshold for the default value, generating the classes.
    thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(image, classes)

    # Using the threshold values, we generate the regions.
    regions = np.digitize(image, bins=thresholds)

    # Plotting the original image.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
    ax[0].imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    ax[0].set_title('Original')
    ax[0].axis('off')

    # Plotting the histogram and the two thresholds obtained from multi-Otsu.
    ax[1].hist(image.ravel(), bins=255)
    ax[1].set_title('Histogram')
    for thresh in thresholds:
        ax[1].axvline(thresh, color='r')

    # Plotting the Multi Otsu result.
    ax[2].imshow(regions, cmap='Accent')
    ax[2].set_title('Multi-Otsu result')
    ax[2].axis('off')

    plt.subplots_adjust()
    plt.show()
    return regions

path = "Path to the first image of the post" # Path to the first image of the post
fileName = "20200509131726.png"
img = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
img = img[148:148+444, 249:249+763, :]
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# applyMultiOtsu(hsv[:,:,0]) # Very discrete information, not used currently.
saturation = applyMultiOtsu(hsv[:,:,1], classes=2) # The S channel also proveds useful information
value = applyMultiOtsu(hsv[:,:,2], classes=2) # The V channel contains most information about the image
```

Comment: you don't need "multi-otsu"(??). you need morphological operations to erase the thin radii while maintaining the shadows of the vertical rods. then you need to manually define a mask to erase all the other stuff in the picture that doesn't move and it outside of where the shadows can be.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier using only 1 pole? You could then just radially spin a pointer at a certain distance around the center of your pole.

For example along a straight line:
[the graph shows the intensity of pixels along the red segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZtS1.png)
(the colors are inverted i have no idea why)

Then figure out at what angle the value is maximal/minimal to get the angle of your pole.

Once you got the angle of your shadow you know where it starts and where it points, walk along that shadow and when it ends you can calculate the length of it.

Additionally what I did is I converted the image to True/False values, then eroded and dilated it to remove any unwanted small lines.

Ps: I wouldn't dare show my terrible code out here but here's what i managed to get after some tinkering [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCvra.png)
And then as Christoph said you should try and clean up/mask out everything outside of you measurement area.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).